# Comparing an NSString with NSNumber in the string

Tags: iphone, nssortdescriptor

Someone else designed this class to have an NSString for an ID (I don't know why to be honest).  So, some objects have @"" for their ID (blank), some have @"id12345" or something to that effect.  I want to sort by the number for my UITableView

First thing I did was use:

```
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"id" withString:@""];
```

so I could get the number.  I'm sure there is a convenience method to get the NSInteger from the NSString, but I just haven't looked it up yet.  Then I kind of got stuck because

since my object, Markers, has a NSString of this ID, how do I sort by the number without replacing the original value in the object?  My initial thoughts were to get the id number from the nsstring and sort.  However, I didn't want to replace the original nsstring either.  The class I have is basically just displaying and sorting the data.

This is what I have so far:

```
- (NSArray *)sortByID:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors {
    for (Marker *m in self.MarkersList) {
        if (![m.id length] == 0) {
            NSString *str = [m.id stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"id" withString:@""];
        // don't know what to do here....
        }
    }
    return [self.MarkersList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see why you're using `sortDescriptors` for here, since you're only sorting by numbers.

I'd use a comparator block (assuming you're on iOS 4 or above) and do it like below:

```
- (NSArray *)sortByID {

 NSArray* orderedList = [self.MarkersList 
                         sortedArrayUsingComparator:^(id obj1, id obj2) 
                     {
                        Marker* m1 = (Marker*) obj1;
                        Marker* m2 = (Marker*) obj2;

                        NSString* str;

                        str = [m1.id stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"id"
                               withString:@""];
                        NSInteger num1 = [str integerValue];

                        str = [m2.id stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"id" 
                               withString:@""];
                        NSInteger num2 = [str integerValue];

                        NSComparisonResult result;
                        if (num1 < num2) {
                            result = NSOrderedAscending;
                        } else if (num1 == num2 ) {
                            result = NSOrderedSame;
                        } else {
                            result = NSOrderedDescending;
                        }

                        return result;
                    }];


return orderedList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you are guaranteed that all your strings look like id######, then after you replace the id from string you can use strings intValue method to get the int value of the string, then just compare the two ints...hope this helps